# Why isn't calling a static method by way of an instance an error for the Java compiler?

Tags: java, static, methods

I'm sure you all know the behaviour I mean - code such as:

```
Thread thread = new Thread();
int activeCount = thread.activeCount();
```

provokes a compiler warning.  Why isn't it an error?

**EDIT:**

To be clear: question has nothing to do with Threads.  I realise Thread examples are often given when discussing this because of the potential to really mess things up with them.  But really the problem is that such usage is *always* nonsense and you can't (competently) write such a call and mean it.  Any example of this type of method call would be barmy.  Here's another:

```
String hello = "hello";
String number123AsString = hello.valueOf(123);
```

Which makes it look as if each String instance comes with a "String valueOf(int i)" method.

Comment: To extend on your point, the redundant instance can even be null: `String hello = null; hello.valueOf(123);` works!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Basically I believe the Java designers made a mistake when they designed the language, and it's too late to fix it due to the compatibility issues involved. Yes, it can lead to very misleading code. Yes, you should avoid it. Yes, you should make sure your IDE is configured to treat it as an error, IMO. Should you ever design a language yourself, bear it in mind as an example of the kind of thing to avoid :)

Just to respond to DJClayworth's point, here's what's allowed in C#:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void Bar()
    {
    }
}

public class Abc
{
    public void Test()
    {
        // Static methods in the same class and base classes
        // (and outer classes) are available, with no
        // qualification
        Def();

        // Static methods in other classes are available via
        // the class name
        Foo.Bar();

        Abc abc = new Abc();

        // This would *not* be legal. It being legal has no benefit,
        // and just allows misleading code
        // abc.Def();
    }

    public static void Def()
    {
    }
}
```

Why do I think it's misleading? Because if I look at code `someVariable.SomeMethod()` I expect it to *use the value of `someVariable`*. If `SomeMethod()` is a static method, that expectation is invalid; the code is tricking me. How can that possibly be a *good* thing?

Bizarrely enough, Java won't let you use a potentially uninitialized variable to call a static method, despite the fact that the only information it's going to use is the declared type of the variable. It's an inconsistent and unhelpful mess. Why allow it?

EDIT: This edit is a response to Clayton's answer, which claims it allows inheritance for static methods. It doesn't. Static methods just aren't polymorphic. Here's a short but complete program to demonstrate that:

```
class Base
{
    static void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("Base.foo()");
    }
}

class Derived extends Base
{
    static void foo()
    {
        System.out.println("Derived.foo()");
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Base b = new Derived();
        b.foo(); // Prints "Base.foo()"
        b = null;
        b.foo(); // Still prints "Base.foo()"
    }
}
```

As you can see, the execution-time value of `b` is completely ignored.

Comment: I think you may be missing something. See my post.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Nope. That's allowed in C#, but someInstanceOfMyClass.doComplexCalculation() wouldn't be.

Comment: @Jon: I ran a similar test and confirmed your findings. Based on that I agree that it's wrong for Java to allow static methods to be called from an instance var. No capability is gained (as I originally thought), but the potential for confusion or error is increased.

Comment: The execution time value of b is completely ignored because you are calling a static method, which depends only on the class of b not its value. All values of type Base have the identical method. You declared Base b so b is a Base , not a Derived . If you had declared Derived b it would have printed "Derived.foo()" .

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, I know... I'm not sure what point you're trying to make. (I wouldn't personally say that "all values of type Base have the identical method" - an instance doesn't "have" a method at all... but I think I know what you mean.)

Comment: The point is that an instance has (as in the OOP "is a / has a" relationships) all of its class members. Only the reverse is not true: a class has only its class members, ie. static members, not any instance members. This syntax is not too different from an instance (or a class) having members through inheritance. As I mentioned in a comment to another answer to this question, the syntax's ambiguity is not too different from an instance method having in its scope an instance member global the whole instance.

Comment: @Matthew: I don't personally think it makes sense to think of static methods in that way - and clearly the C# designers didn't either, avoiding pointless bugs.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : Well, the C++ designers seemed to think this syntax is OK. It also allows the practical use I mentioned in my comment on another answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co/610674?noredirect=1#comment73126254_610463 .

Comment: @Matthew: That "practical use" wouldn't be applicable in either Java or C#, so it makes more sense to prohibit it. C++ is a different language in many, many ways.

Comment: C# is also a different language. Why wouldn't my practical example be "applicable" in Java? If you want a single method to accept an instance that could be type Base or type Derived, and call the static method appropriate to either, why wouldn't you use the simple, clear inheritance pattern I applied? Otherwise you have to use conditionals or something else brittle/verbose.

Comment: @Matthew: Because it would be a violation of what `static` means *everywhere* else in the language. A static method is not associated with an instance of the type; it's associated with just the type itself. Likewise static methods just *don't* override each other. If you're saying "The language should have been designed completely differently" then that's one thing, but it's *not* an excuse for the way Java actually works at the moment (in terms of allowing this access) - and the "benefit" you're espousing doesn't even work in Java anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139052/discussion-between-matthew-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: I am using IntelliJ 2017 and the default behavior is to NOT auto complete static methods when using instance. If you do it anyway, it sets a warning (but this action is done by the IDE, not the compiler).

Answer (score 15):

Why should it be an error?  The instance has access to all the static methods.  The static methods can't change the state of the instance (trying to *is* a compile error).

The problem with the well-known example that you give is very specific to *threads*, not static method calls.  It looks as though you're getting the `activeCount()` for the thread referred to by `thread`, but you're really getting the count for the calling thread.  This is a logical error that you as a programmer are making.  Issuing a warning is the appropriate thing for the compiler to do in this case.  It's up to you to heed the warning and fix your code.

EDIT: I realize that the syntax of the language is what's *allowing* you to write misleading code, but remember that the compiler and its warnings are part of the language too.  The language allows you to do something that the compiler considers dubious, but it gives you the warning to make sure you're aware that it could cause problems.

Comment: It's irrelevant to the *instance*. The only thing is the *declared type* of the variable. It's a horrible, horrible misfeature and a mistake on the part of the language designers, IMO.

Comment: Yes, it's irrelevant to the instance, but I don't think calling a static method from an instance should be a full-fledged error.  It's just really bad style.  IMHO, a class should either be all static methods, or the static methods should be private, but I wouldn't want the compiler to enforce that.

Comment: @Bill: I don't think it even gave a warning in the early days. The warning was added because it was misleading people. What's the *benefit* in allowing it?

Comment: @Bill: Put it this way - if Java *didn't* allow it and someone suggested that it *should* allow it, what would your reaction be? Would you really argue in favour of it? Or would you argue (as I do) that it's a pointless feature which needlessly allows misleading code?

Comment: @Jon: The benefit in allowing it could probably only be expressed in compile time. There's no reason from our perspective to need to call a static method from an instance. Since no other language feature would disallow it, the earliest implementors probably left it out as seemingly needless check.

Comment: @Jon: I do agree, though, that if it were an error from the beginning, I would not argue in favor of allowing it. You can already call <Class>.staticMethod(), so there's really no need for <instance>.staticMethod().

Comment: I don't buy the "compile time" reason - it's obvious that you're looking up the method via a reference; how long does it then take to check whether or not it's static? I think it's easier just to consider it a language design mistake.

Comment: But not having the hindsight of seeing all the bad code we would write without a warning for that, why would you put an extra check in when you're writing the compiler?  The reference has access to static methods, so the warning requires extra code to check for it.

Comment: When you're writing the compiler, you're bound by the language. However, I'd say that when designing the language you should recognise that it's a mistake to allow it. Anything reached via an expression should depend on the value of that expression in some way.

Comment: I don't know how obvious it is without the benefit of hindsight. There's good reason to allow access to static member variables and methods from an instance of a class. It doesn't seem like much of a stretch to allow it from references as well. Most of the time it's harmless for reasons <continued>

Comment: ...I've already explained. It's not until you're shown the bad code examples that it gives rise to that it's obviously not a good thing.

Comment: That's why most of us shouldn't be language designers :)

Comment: No, as far as I know no one, not even McCarthy, gets it right the first time.  Besides, I'm much more adept at complaining about existing languages. :)

Answer (score 11):

They cannot make it an error anymore, because of all the code that is already out there.

I am with you on that it should be an error.
Maybe there should be an option/profile for the compiler to upgrade some warnings to errors.

**Update:** When they introduced the *assert* keyword in 1.4, which has similar potential compatibility issues with old code, they made it [available only if you explicitly set the source mode to "1.4"](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html#compatibility). I suppose one could make a it an error in a new source mode "java 7". But I doubt they would do it, considering that all the hassle it would cause. As others have pointed out, it is not strictly necessary to prevent you from writing confusing code. And language changes to Java should be limited to the strictly necessary at this point.

Comment: There is such option in Eclipse compiler (indirectStatic, http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm)

Comment: But they did this when they introduced the assert keyword in Java 1.4. Why can't they do it again in the same way?

Comment: You're right. For Assert, you have to specifically set the compiler level to 1.4, otherwise it still compiles without assert. I suppose 1.5 annotations and generics work the same. So one could have a Java 7 compile level, that would make it an error.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer - the language allows it, so its not an error.

Answer (score 3):

The really important thing, from the compiler's perspective, is that it be able to resolve symbols.  In the case of a static method, it needs to know what class to look in for it -- since it's not associated with any particular object.  Java's designers obviously decided that since they could determine the class of an object, they could also resolve the class of any static method for that object from any instance of the object.  They choose to allow this -- swayed, perhaps, by @TofuBeer's observation -- to give the programmer some convenience.  Other language designers have made different choices.  I probably would have fallen into the latter camp, but it's not that big of a deal to me.  I probably would allow the usage that @TofuBeer mentions, but having allowed it my position on not allowing access from an instance variable is less tenable.

Answer (score 2):

Likely for the same logical that makes this not an error:

```
public class X
{
    public static void foo()
    {
    }

    public void bar()
    {
        foo(); // no need to do X.foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't an error because it's part of the spec, but you're obviously asking about the rationale, which we can all guess at.

My guess is that the source of this is actually to allow a method in a class to invoke a static method in the same class without the hassle. Since calling x() is legal (even without the self class name), calling this.x() should be legal as well, and therefore calling via any object was made legal as well.

This also helps encourage users to turn private functions into static if they don't change the state.

Besides, compilers generally try to avoid declaring errors when there is no way that this could lead to a direct error. Since a static method does not change the state or care about the invoking object, it does not cause an actual error (just confusion) to allow this. A warning suffices.

Comment: @Uri: It's easy enough to make it available within the current class without specifying the class name. C# managed it, and Java compilers manage to tell the difference (as you won't get a warning in that case) so why should it be specified this way?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the instance variable reference is only to supply the type which encloses the static. If you look at the byte code invoking a static via instance.staticMethod or EnclosingClass.staticMethod produces the same invoke static method bytecode. No reference to the instance appears.

The answer as too why it's in there, well it just is. As long as you use the class. and not via an instance you will help avoid confusion in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can change it in your IDE (in Eclipse Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings)

Answer (score 0):

There's not option for it. In java (like many other lang.) you can have access to all static members of a class through its class name or instance object of that class. That would be up to you and your case and software solution which one you should use that gives you more readability.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty old topic but still up-to-date and surprisingly bringing higher impact nowadays. As Jon mentioned, it might be just a mistake Java's designers made at the very beginning. But I wouldn't imagine before it can have impact on security.

Many coders know Apache Velocity, flexible and powerful template engine. It's so powerful that it allows to feed template with a set of named objects - stricly considered as objects from programming language (Java originally). Those objects can be accessed from within template like in programming language so for example Java's String instance can be used with all its public fields, properties and methods

```
$input.isEmpty()
```

where *input* is a *String*, runs directly through JVM and returns *true* or *false* to Velocity parser's output). So far so good.

But in Java all objects inherit from *Object* so our end-users can also put this to the template

```
$input.getClass()
```

to get an instance of *String* Class.

And with this reference they can also call a **static** method *forName(String)* on this

```
$input.getClass().forName("java.io.FileDescriptor")
```

use any class name and use it to whatever web server's account can do (deface, steal DB content, inspect config files, ...)

This exploit is somehow (in specific context) described here: https://github.com/veracode-research/solr-injection#7-cve-2019-17558-rce-via-velocity-template-by-_s00py

It wouldn't be possible if calling static methods from reference to the instance of class was prohibited.

I'm not saying that a particular programming framework is better than the other one or so but I just want to put a comparison. There's a port of Apache Velocity for .NET. In C# it's not possible to call static methods just from instance's reference what makes exploit like this useless:

```
$input.GetType().GetType("System.IO.FileStream, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")
```

Answer (score -9):

I just consider this:

```
instanceVar.staticMethod();
```

to be shorthand for this:

```
instanceVar.getClass().staticMethod();
```

If you always had to do this:

```
SomeClass.staticMethod();
```

then you wouldn't be able to leverage inheritance for static methods.

That is, by calling the static method via the instance you don't need to know what concrete class the instance is at compile time, only that it implements staticMethod() somewhere along the inheritance chain.

EDIT:  This answer is wrong.  See comments for details.

Comment: Good, that's another reason why it shouldn't be allowed - because you're being misled too. It doesn't act as you want it to. It will *only* use the *declared* type of "instanceVar" in your example. Heck, the value of instanceVar can even be null.

Comment: @Jon: I was under the impression that getClass() would give you the actual class of the object, not the declared type of the variable.  Javadoc is unclear on this issue, so I'm going to test it.

Comment: @Clayton: Yes, but it doesn't call getClass(). I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: (And if it *did* call getClass(), it couldn't then call staticMethod(), because that isn't a method on Class<T>.)

Comment: @Jon: I stand corrected. instance.getClass().staticMethod() wouldn't compile. instance.staticMethod() went to the declared class, not the actual class.  It seems there's no way to call a static method of an instance var's superclass from the instance, at least not without resorting to Reflection.

Comment: You could potentially delete it, and I can edit my post to not refer to it.

Comment: @Jon: I'm going to leave it here. I learn as much from mistakes as anything else, so it might help someone else to see this.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Clayton: You may want to make this community wiki so we can downvote it without penalizing you.

Comment: @BilltheLizard and penalizing us :)