# List reports all objects within as being the same java?

Tags: java, list

Im using a list of objects (Area) in java, which i defined as so:

```
    public static List<Area> areaList = new ArrayList<Area>();
```

I add content to my list as so:

```
    areaList.add(new Area(px, py, pz, radius, wl));
```

then i access the list, to check each of the Area's within it like so:

```
for (int i = 1; i < areaList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(areaList.get(i).somevariable));
}
```

(ignore the 'somevariable' and i also didnt use println(), this was for example, the way i accessed using:

```
areaList.get(i)
```

is whats important here)

But it returns all the objects inside the List as having the same values - that of the last one accessed.

Can anyone tell me where im going wrong?

Comment: The error is not in the code you show. Please create a complete but minimal example that exposes the error (see http://sscce.org).

Comment: How do you fill the list? Where do `px`, `py`, `pz`, `radius` and `wl` come from? Just a note: Java uses 0 based indexing (see your for loop).

Comment: Are you intentionally skipping element 0? Also consider using the for each construct, `for(Area a : areaList) { println(a.somevariable); }`

Comment: the variables arent too important, as they are for other parts of the program, it is a bukkit plugin, i have uploaded the complete source code here: http://hyperarray.x10.mx/minecraft/plugins/main.zip which contains 3 classes, but what other parts of the code would you need? i have given you the only part of the code which writes to the list?

Comment: I had a look through the code. You can find my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through your uploaded code and found the error.

You declared every field in the class `Area` as **static**:

```
public class Area {
    public static int posx;
    public static int posy;
    public static int posz;
}
```

The fields are therefore equals for all instances, because there is just one `posx` field for the class `Area` (read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913560/what-is-static) and the answers for details). Because of this every write to, e. g., `posx` overrides the old value. Remove the `static` keyword and then all instances of the class `Area` have their own instance variable.

You should also think about making them private and provide getter and setter methods.

I haven't looked in detail through your code, but there are several places where you used `static` variables. You should revisit this.

Comment: oh right, thank you i need to revise static, this was informative :D

Answer (score 1):

It's not the solution but you should begin your loop with `i=0`

Comment: i did sorry this was after i was trying some different things

Answer (score 0):

You can try printing out `hashcode()` of each object to see if they are really the same, provided that is not overridden.

Also you are starting your iteration at `1`, you need to start at `0` to iterate over the entire collection.

Comment: I believe ArrayList should only look at the equals method. Naturally, the hashCode method should be written accordingly, but that wouldn't be the source of the error here

Comment: Right, but `hashcode` gives you something to print out to see if they are actually referring to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to start with i=1 instead of i = 0? This might be relevant if you are running your tests with only two objects