# What does static refer to being "stuck" to?

Tags: static, terminology

I'm trying to give myself a mapped idea of the word static (using my current noun definition of static, not having a good understanding of the adjective definition), but it would seem that non-static variables and methods actually are "stuck" (or better said referencing/referring) to objects/instances.    So what is the terminology static actually describing about the declared methods/variables?

Comment: It depends on the context. What programming language are we talking about?

Comment: Static is "stuck" to the class.  Non-statics are "stuck" to instances of the class.

Comment: @MattBall  I was refering to Java, but now that I am more familiar with other languages (JS, python, ruby), would you care to add an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words "static" and "dynamic" are frequently used as opposites in programming terminology.

Something that is dynamic is something that changes; in the context of a class, it is something that takes on different values or behaviors with each instance (object).

Something that is static does not change; it is in stasis.  So a static variable of a class does not take on different values with each instance.

Static electricity doesn't move; it is stuck in one place, on your socks.  Dynamic electricity, in motion in a wire, can do much more powerful things.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question here provides a very detailed answer: [What is "static"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913560/what-is-static)

The concept of `static` has to do with whether something is part of a class or an object (instance).

In the case of the `main` method which is declared as `static`, it says that the `main` method is an class method -- a method that is part of a class, not part of an object. This means that another class could call a class method of another class, by referring to the `ClassName.method`. For example, invoking the run method of `MyClass` would be accomplished by:

```
MyClass.main(new String[]{"parameter1", "parameter2"});
```

On the other hand, a method or field without the `static` modifier means that it is part of an object (or also called "instance") and not a part of a class. It is referred to by the name of the specific object to which the method or field belongs to, rather than the class name:

```
MyClass c1 = new MyClass();
c1.getInfo()     // "getInfo" is an instance method of the object "c1"
```

As each instance could have different values, the values of a method or field with the same name in different objects don't necessarily have to be the same:

```
MyClass c1 = getAnotherInstance();
MyClass c2 = getAnotherInstance();

c1.value     // The field "value" for "c1" contains 10.
c2.value     // The field "value" for "c2" contains 12.
             // Because "c1" and "c2" are different instances, and 
             // "value" is an instance field, they can contain different
             // values.
```

Combining the two concepts of instance and class variables. Let's say we declare a new class which contains both instance and class variables and methods:

```
class AnotherClass {
    private int instanceVariable;
    private static int classVariable = 42;

    public int getInstanceVariable() {
        return instanceVariable;
    }

    public static int getClassVariable() {
        return classVariable;
    }

    public AnotherClass(int i) {
        instanceVariable = i;
    }
}
```

The above class has an instance variable `instanceVariable`, and a class variable `classVariable` which is declared with a `static` modifier. Similarly, there is a instance and class method to retrieve the values.

The constructor for the instance takes a value to assign to the instance variable as the argument. The class variable is initialized to be `42` and never changed.

Let's actually use the above class and see what happens:

```
AnotherClass ac1 = new AnotherClass(10);

ac1.getInstanceVariable();             // Returns "10"
AnotherClass.getClassVariable();       // Returns "42"
```

Notice the different ways the class and instance methods are called. The way they refer to the class by the name `AnotherClass`, or the instance by the name `ac1`. Let's go further and see the behavioral differences of the methods:

```
AnotherClass ac1 = new AnotherClass(10);
AnotherClass ac2 = new AnotherClass(20);

ac1.getInstanceVariable();             // Returns "10"
AnotherClass.getClassVariable();       // Returns "42"
ac2.getInstanceVariable();             // Returns "20"
AnotherClass.getClassVariable();       // Returns "42"
```

As can be seen, an instance variable is one that is held by an object (or "instance"), therefore unique to that particular instance, which in this example is the objects referred to by `ac1` and `ac2`.

A class variable on the other hand is only unique to that entire class. To get this point across even better, let's add a new method to the `AnotherClass`:

```
public int getClassVariableFromInstance() {
    return classVariable;
}
```

Then, run the following:

```
AnotherClass ac1 = new AnotherClass(10);
AnotherClass ac2 = new AnotherClass(20);

ac1.getInstanceVariable();             // Returns "10"
ac1.getClassVariableFromInstance();    // Returns "42"
ac2.getInstanceVariable();             // Returns "20"
ac2.getClassVariableFromInstance();    // Returns "42"
```

Although `getClassVariableFromInstance` is an instance method, as can be seen by being invoked by referring to the instances `ac1` and `ac2`, they both return the same value, `42`. This is because in both instance methods, they refer to the class method `classVariable` which is unique to the class, not to the instance -- there is only a single copy of `classVariable` for the class `AnotherClass`.

I hope that some what clarifies what the `static` modifier is used for.

[The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) from Sun has a section called [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), which also goes into the two types of variables and methods.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.