# Calling static method on a class?

Tags: java, class, static-methods

Say, I have a reference to a Class object with SomeType having a static method. Is there a way to call that method w/o instantiating SomeType first? Preferably not escaping strong typing.

EDIT: OK, I've screwed up.

```
interface Int{
    void someMethod();
}

class ImplOne implements Int{
    public void someMethod() {
        // do something
    }
}

Class<? extends Int> getInt(){
    return ImplOne.class;
}
```

In this case someMethod() can't be static anyways.

Comment: I think that this question is actually about Java reflection, but it's not actually clear.

Comment: I don't see any static methods - funny yeah !

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A static method, by definition, is called on a class and not on an instance of that class.

So if you use:

```
SomeClass.someStaticMethod()
```

you are instantiating nothing (leave aside the class loading and instantiation of the `SomeClass` class itself, which the JVM handles and is way out of your scope).

This is opposed to a regular method called on an object, which has already been instantiated:

```
SomeObject o = someObject; // had to be instantiated *somewhere*
o.someMethod();
```

Comment: Eclipse (and quite possibly other IDEs) even offers to warn you if you're calling a static method using instance syntax ("Non-static access to static member", it's called).  It's not an error, but it's a little less clear than using explicitly static access.

Comment: I think Sun's compiler itself issues that warning, too, now. I believe it is confusing enough that it should be made an error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-com

Answer (score 40):

I'm not sure exactly what the situation is, but if you're looking to execute the static method on a class without knowing the class type (i.e. you don't know it's SomeType, you just have the Class object), if you know the name and parameters of the method you could use reflection and do this:

```
Class c = getThisClassObjectFromSomewhere();

//myStaticMethod takes a Double and String as an argument
Method m = c.getMethod("myStaticMethod", Double.class, String.class);
Object result = m.invoke(null, 1.5, "foo");
```

Answer (score 16):

Since you talk about a Class object, I assume that you're interested in Java reflection. Here's a brief snippet that does what you're trying to do:

```
Class someClass = SomeType.class;
Method staticMethod = someClass.getMethod( "methodName", ... );

// pass the first arg as null to invoke a static method
staticMethod.invoke( null, ... );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  That's what static methods are all about.  Just call it.  SomeType.yourStaticMethodHere().