# Notify List Adapter when Firebase Notification is received

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add a new element to a listview when a notification is received(**without users click**).

I need to listen to received notification on my fragment, then add a new element to adapter based on notification info.

How can i listen to new notifications from a fragment?

I've already implemented the Firebase Cloud Messaging architecture.

-MyFirebaseMessagingService......

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the Arraylist and adapter as public in fragment and in MyFirebaseMessagingService update this method

```
private void handleNotification(final String message) {

if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {

//add message to list
Fragment.list.add(message);
Fragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
       pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);                                                                                                                                         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        // play notification sound
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();

    } else {
        // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public String push_receiver = "com.example.fragment.GCMBroadCast";
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mActivity.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(push_receiver_expositor));
    }

    /** receiving GCM broadcast */
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make one broadcast receiver in your fragment and when your firebase notification receive at a time you also call yor fragment receiver by below line

```
public String push_receiver = "com.example.fragment.GCMBroadCast";
Intent intent = new Intent(push_receiver);
                    intent.putExtra("extra", bundle);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: What would be the intent filter when register the broadcastreceiver? LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mYourBroadcastReceiver,
    new IntentFilter(?));

Answer (score 0):

1. Create static method and call it from `MyFirebaseMessagingService`. [reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834005/calling-static-method-from-another-java-class) , [reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942326/calling-static-method-on-a-class)
2. Create [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
3. Use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).