# How come invoking a (static) method on a null reference doesn't throw NullPointerException?

Tags: java, static, null, nullpointerexception

I wrote this program in Java

```
public class Why {

  public static void test() {
    System.out.println("Passed");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Why NULL = null;
    NULL.test();
  }

}
```

I read that invoking a method on a `null` object causes `NullPointerException`, and yet the above program doesn't? Why is this? Am I not understanding something correctly?

Comment: A static member variable is created as soon as the class is loaded by the Java interpreter, and the initialization is also done at that time.

Comment: Since you're learning, you should familiarize yourself with the coding convention: http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html : specifically, all-uppercase names are reserved for constants.

Comment: ...although I suppose that may be your intention in the first place since you probably wanted `NULL` to always be `null`, in which case you'll probably want to learn about `final` keyword and what it means for fields vs local variables (and classes and methods).

Comment: Here you can find compiler level implementation of static. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21037406/1686291

Comment: It might be interesting to know that, when accessing the method through `Why[] w = new Why[2]; w[3].test();` there will be an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: i loved it `Why NULL = null;`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`test()` is a `static` method. A `static` member belongs to the type, and do not require an instance to access.

A `static` member should *ONLY* be accessed via a type expression. That is, you should've written it as follows:

```
Why.test(); // always invoke static method on the type it belongs to!
```

Java does allow you to access a `static` member via an object reference expression, but
this is *VERY* misleading, since this is *NOT* the actual semantics of a `static` member access.

```
Why aNull = null; 
aNull.test(); // DO NOT EVER DO THIS!
// invokes Why.test(), does NOT throw NullPointerException
```

When accessing a `static` member through an object reference expression, only the declared type of the reference matters. This means that:

- It doesn't matter if the reference is actually `null`, since no instance is required
- If the reference is not `null`, it doesn't matter what the runtime type of the object is, *there is no dynamic dispatch*!!!

As you can see, the exact opposites are true on both points for instance member access. This is why `static` members should *NEVER* be accessed in a "non-`static`" way, because it gives a very misleading appearance on what it's actually doing.

#### Related questions

- [Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods) (understanding `this` is crucial!)
- [Why isn’t calling a static method by way of an instance an error for the Java compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-com)

Answer (score 4):

Static methods do not need a reference to the object.  So you can call it even reference to the object is null.   That's how main method works.

Try removing static designation from the object to see the null pointer exception.

Answer (score 3):

It's a static method, which allows you to call methods on it without instantiating an instance.

Answer (score 3):

You should turn on the various warnings in your IDE.  Chances are you will see a warning about accessing a static member in a non-static way.

You could do something like (Why)(null).test(), it is only using the (Why)(null) to get the class.

Comment: `(Why)(null)` is not valid Java syntax. The correct syntax is `((Why) null)`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Static Variable & Methods are associated with the class, rather than with any object. Every instance of the class shares a class variable, which is in one fixed location in memory.

Any object can change the value of a class variable, but class variables can also be manipulated without creating an instance of the class and the same apply for Static Method.
for more [refer this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1).