# Force method call on null variable to throw a NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading, null, nullpointerexception, operation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How come invoking a (static) method on a null reference doesn’t throw NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293353/how-come-invoking-a-static-method-on-a-null-reference-doesnt-throw-nullpointe)
>   [Static fields on a null reference in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579953/static-fields-on-a-null-reference-in-java)

I tried the code from [this old video](http://www.metacafe.com/watch/370425/impossible_java_program/):

```
class Impossible {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = null;
        System.out.println(t.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

Output: `main`

Well, just what the heck is that?! Does `java.lang.Thread` breach any the `NullPointerException` rule?

But what I'm most interested in it: **How can I make that variable behave to throw a NullPointerException?**

Comment: I'm aware of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293353/how-come-invoking-a-static-method-on-a-null-reference-doesnt-throw-nullpointe).

Comment: If you want the fastest way to ensure an NPE is thrown just call the `.getClass();` method. Had the advantage of not increasing branch count in code coverage

Comment: @RefLibApi So you know it is not possible to throw a NPE but are asking how to throw a NPE... Not sure I follow you.

Comment: NPE gave us a [nice answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13540062/1849186), don't pick on the good man. btw I'm stubborn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does java.lang.Thread breach any the NullPointerException rule?

**No**, reason for a `NPE` been thrown is not related to a `class`. It is related to an `instance` of that class, on which invocation is done. Also, it depends upon which type of method, or field you are accessing.

What is happening here is, `currentThread()` is a static method of Thread class. Which is boudn to a class, rather than an instance. So, even if you invoke it on a reference of Thread class, it is actually invoked on class name.

So,

```
Thread t = null
t.currentThread();
```

is actually invoked as: -

```
Thread.currentThread();
```

So, when accessing a static member through an object reference expression, only the declared type of the reference matters. This means that:

- It doesn't matter if the reference is actually pointing to null, since no
  instance is required.
- If the reference is not null, it doesn't matter what the type
  of the object the reference is pointing to, there is no dynamic dispatch.

---

> How can I make that variable behave to throw a NullPointerException?

Well, the current print statement will never throw a `NPE`. The first part is already explained above. Now, let's move ahead.

```
Thread.currentThread();
```

The above invocation will never return `null`. It always returns the current thread instance. And in Java, you are always inside one or the other thread. Even when inside `public static void main` method, you are executing the `Main Thread`. So, `currentThread` can't be `null`.

And hence, further invocation: -

```
Thread.currentThread().getName();
```

will work fine, and return the name of current thread.

Comment: Alright, the second part made it clear for me, thanks. =(

Comment: @RefLibApi.. I thought that is the thing which might be confusing you. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

`currentThread()` is a `static` method of class `Thread`. This means that it's not associated with any particular instance of the class, but with the class itself.

With this in mind, `t.currentThread()` is simply a different way of saying `Thread.currentThread()`. The value of `t` is not used at all, so it doesn't matter whether `t` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

[You can't throw a NullPointerException by calling a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579953/static-fields-on-a-null-reference-in-java). So you need to call an instance method - any instance method would do, for example:

```
t.checkAccess();
t.getId();
t.getName();
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you see that code inside your development env (Eclipse / Netbeans) you would have seen at the first moment that `currentThread()` is written cursive, which clearly indicates that it is a static method (Class method).

Further, If you have checkstyle enabled, it will warn you to not call static methods on instances of an object.

The question is a bit of a Foul, because the Code formatting here cannot display static methods differently formatted.

And to finally answer the question: The Class Thread is never null, instances of an class can be null.