# No Nullpointer exception even object is pointed to null

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Static fields on a null reference in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579953/static-fields-on-a-null-reference-in-java)

I am new to Java. I know if any object point to and if we try to perform any operation on that object, a Nullpointer exception is thrown by JVM. But in my case there is no Nullpointer exception please help me ?. Below is my code

```
public class Employee
{

     public static String empName = "John"

     public static void main(String args[])
     {
           Employee emp = new Employee();    
           emp = null;
           System.out.println(emp.empName);
      }   
}
```

It prints **John** as output even emp object is pointion to null. But I am expecting a nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because field is `static`.
In your case `emp.empName` equals to `Employee.empName`

Answer (score 3):

Since you are accessing a static variable, so you will not get NPE if your reference is referencing null. This is because static fields are bound to `class` rather than any instance.

So, for static variable: -

```
Employee emp = null;
emp.empName;  // This is evaluated as `Employee.empName;`
```

So, only the reference type is used. Regardless of whether that reference is pointing to `null`, or any subclass object.

Answer (score 0):

As `empName` is **static** the call would be `Employee.empName` in the **byte code**, Thus no NPE:

**original Code:** `System.out.println(emp.empName);`

**Byte code:**       `GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
                      GETSTATIC oops/Employee.empName : Ljava/lang/String;`