# How can a null reference to an interface return a value?

Tags: java

the code is :

```
interface I {
    int i = 0;
    void display();
}

class A implements I {
    I i1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.display();
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(i1); //1
        System.out.println(i1.i); //2
    }
}
```

The output of the code is

```
null
0
```

But when the address of the `i` is `null`, then in the 2nd `i1.i` how does it return a value ?
How can a null reference be used to point to a variable ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579953/static-fields-on-a-null-reference-in-java

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Fields declared in interfaces are implicitly `static`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3)

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly `public`, `static`, and `final`. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.

This

```
i1.i
```

is a `static` field access expression. It relies on the type of `i1`, not its value. It is exactly equivalent to

```
I.i // where I is the name of your interface
```

Comment: And this is why it isn't a good idea to access static fields through an instance, even though Java allows you to do so.

Comment: "Fields declared in interfaces are implicitly static" and final.

Comment: I believe Eclipse even issues a warning when you do that, it's a bad practice in general (though sometimes it's desirable)