# NullPointerException in ByteBuffer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
byteArray = new byte[10000];

-- some code here ----

byteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
for (int i=0; byteBuffer.hasRemaining(); i++)
{
    shortArray[i] = byteBuffer.getShort();
    System.out.println(shortArray[i]);
}
```

The `byteBuffer.hasRemaining()` gets flagged with a `NullPointerException` although I have provided it with a backing array.

What is the problem here?

Comment: where you initialize `byteBuffer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, check how you initialize `byteBuffer` it should be something like this since `wrap` is a static method

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[10000];    
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
```

Comment: What happens when you call `static` methods on `null` objects?

Comment: @JanDvorak Alright, I realized my mistake :) Next, getting Shorts out of the buffer. `getShort()` is abstract.

Comment: @JanDvorak, really no idea. Please, let us now.

Comment: @LittleChild `getShort` is abstract but it still needs to be implemented by concrete subclasses (of which `wrap` returns one). Try calling it.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293353/how-come-invoking-a-static-method-on-a-null-reference-doesnt-throw-nullpointe

Answer (score 1):

The code seems OK. I suspect this is (due to some bug) because byteBuffer variable = null

Comment: `hasRemaining` is not static, so the exception does get thrown at that point, so it's not a bug.