# Invoke static method in Java Debugger Interface (JDI)

Tags: java, static, jdi

In JDI, there is [a method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ObjectReference.html#invokeMethod%28com.sun.jdi.ThreadReference,%20com.sun.jdi.Method,%20java.util.List,%20int%29)

```
 Value ObjectReference.invokeMethod(ThreadReference, Method, args list, int options)
```

that invokes a method in the target (debuggee) VM.

But how can I call a static method? In such a case, I don't have an object reference.

TIL Java lets you [call static methods on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293353/how-come-invoking-a-static-method-on-a-null-reference-doesnt-throw-nullpointe), but this does not work here.

What would make sense is

```
 static Value ReferenceType.invokeStaticMethod(ThreadReference, Method, etc)
```

but no such thing exists, and I cannot for the life of me figure out a way to do by any other means either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClassType` extends `ReferenceType` which should give you what you want. See [`ClassType.invokeMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ClassType.html#invokeMethod%28com.sun.jdi.ThreadReference,%20com.sun.jdi.Method,%20java.util.List,%20int%29).

Comment: Hey! Is there a way that I use `invokeMethod` and the thread does not resume? I have seen IDEs that allow evaluating expression and the thread does not resume. Any idea how it is implemented?