# NullPointerException or will print the static variable's content

Tags: java, static, nullpointerexception, static-members

I came across following code :

```
public class TradingSystem {

    private static String category = "electronic trading system";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TradingSystem system = null;
        System.out.println(system.category);
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/H5PSNE) :
electronic trading system

I was surprised to not find a NullPointerException !

Q1. Why didn't it throw the `NullPointerException` ?

Q2. Or while compile time, due to category's declaration having `static` made it to replace the system(i.e object reference) with `TradingSystem` and as such essentially `TradingSystem.category` was called?

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293353/how-come-invoking-a-static-method-on-a-null-reference-doesnt-throw-nullpointe

Comment: @Raedwald technically, that's not exactly duplicate to this. but good to know

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java allows accessing class variables (i.e. `static` ones) using the instance syntax. In other words, the compiler lets you write `system.category`, but it resolves it to `TradingSystem.category`, which is independent of the instance on which it is accessed.

That is why you do not get `NullPointerException`. However, this syntax is not readable and confusing. That is why you should get a warning and a suggestion to use `TradingSystem.category` instead of `system.category`.

Comment: so my second proposition in second question was correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not different from following code conceptually.

```
public class TradingSystem {

    private static String category = "electronic trading system";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TradingSystem.category);

    }
}
```

Even though you seem to be using system object reference, you are actually using static value. Java allows use instances when you use static,but you should prefer above syntax so that it is clear that you are using static ones.

Answer (score 1):

You should never call static methods using class instances, nor is it ever needed. As static methods are executed at the class level, the instance is not used and thus no null pointer exception is thrown.

Comment: I think "should never call ..." is too harsh. Why? If so, JAVA would have never allowed syntactically to allow that, but it does. why? because anything that belongs to a Class naturally belongs to its instances and how it should be called is subject to the context. at least in literal sense.

Comment: @KNU I disagree. I don't know why Java allows this way of calling static methods (my guess is to successfully compile code that it otherwise could not) but it only leads to unexpected behaviour. Can you give an example where this is beneficial?

Comment: @Konard I am not saying it might be beneficial but it might be more meaningful/practical to use reference. e.g. Clients need not know if the method is static/non-static while using them as Static members can be called from both the static & non-static context.

Comment: more on "why Java allows this way of calling " because think in real world anything that is known to template must also be implicitly known to the object created using that template. isn't it.Hence, IMO, Java devs have deliberately allowed it.

Answer (score 1):

static is said to be "OF CLASS" not for object of a class. So here

System.out.println(system.category); "system is acting as TradingSystem"

which is right. As you do not need instantiated object to evoke static marked field or method.