# Strange Code Output

Tags: java

I've stumbled across some pretty weird code that I'm surprised doesn't cause an error

```
public class WeirdCode {

    public static int fooField = 42;

    public WeirdCode getFoo(){
        return null; 
    } 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        WeirdCode foo = new WeirdCode();
        System.out.println(foo.getFoo().fooField); 
    }
}
```

Surprisingly, it prints out 42! Can anyone explain?

Comment: What did you expect it'd return?

Comment: @ReutSharabani I thought it would throw a NullPointerException

Comment: I think the downvoters didn't really read the code all the way through.  This is not a bad question.  I certainly thought it was going to throw. Thanks for allowing me to learn something new. +1

Comment: @sstan Thanks, I'm glad we both learned something new then

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come invoking a (static) method on a null reference doesn't throw NullPointerException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293353/how-come-invoking-a-static-method-on-a-null-reference-doesnt-throw-nullpointe)

Comment: @Michael I actually thought about it again after reading the explanation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

References to static members of a class are resolved at compile-time. The compiler doesn't care what the value of the expression is, just its type, and so a `((WeirdCode) null).fooField` just resolves to `WeirdCode.fooField` like anything else.