# Sleeping a thread statically versus using its instance

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the difference between -

```
Thread workerThread = new Thread(runnable);
workerThread.start();
workerThread.sleep(5000);
.....
```

And

```
Thread workerThread = new Thread(runnable);
workerThread.start();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Do they both cause worker thread to pause sleep?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static method in Java can be accessed using object instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978000/static-method-in-java-can-be-accessed-using-object-instance)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No** sleep is a static method that affects the current thread: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)

So there is no difference, they both won't do what you want. The use of static methods on an instance is <strike>deprecated</strike> discouraged since it make you think you can do something you actually can't (like in this case)

Small addition - see John's answer to [why calling static methods from class instances is allowed in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-com) `:-)`

Comment: +1: I am not sure it it deprecated in the sense that some methods are `@Deprecated`. However, it is highly discouraged as it doesn't do what it appears it should, as you say.

Comment: @Peter - thanks. english is not my native language, so these comments are very very welcome :)

Comment: @MByD, English is my native language but corrections, clarifications and quibbles are always welcome. I can always improve. ;)

Comment: "The use of static methods on an instance is deprecated discouraged since it make you think you can do something you actually can't (like in this case)" What do you mean, I can't pause the worker thread for 5 seconds ?

Comment: If you want to pause the worker thread, you will have to do that from within it.

Comment: Short note: using an IDE you can make it warn you if you call static methods on an instance (at least eclipse can)

Answer (score 4):

`sleep` in both instances is the same static method that would cause the currently executing thread to sleep, not the workerThread.

Answer (score 3):

The only actual call is

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

The other is an oddity of java that you can call static method's through instance variables.

You should always use

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

As it is better self-documenting that it is the current thread 'always' that is being slept on. If you do

```
myThread.sleep(5000);
```

You are not sleeping the myThread thread, you are sleeping the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

The second one should be preferred, because Thread.sleep is a static method, and should thus always be invoked, like all static methods, on the class defining it rather than on an instance of this class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility.  Use a volatile flag to pass the message to C.

```
volatile boolean startC = false;

void B() {
  // Do initial B work.
  startC = true;  // Set the volatile flag.
  // Finish B processing not relevant to C.
}

void C() {
  // Wait for B to progress far enough.
  while (!startC) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
  }
  // B has done enough work so we can begin.
}
```

This is not real code, just enough to give you the idea of what I am getting at.  For example, you will need to pay attention to the visibility of the startC flag, or write a public getter and setter for it so B() and C() both have access.