# What's the difference between calling through and object vs class

Tags: java

What's the difference between calling a method through an object vs a class.

for example the Class Bob

```
public class SecretNumber() {
    public static int secretNumber = 2;
    public static void changeSecretNumber(){
        secretNumber++;
    }
}
```

What would be the difference if i called it like an object

```
SecretNumber secretNumber = new SecretNumber();
secretNumber.changeSecretNumber();
```

vs calling it like this

```
SecretNumber.changeSecretNumber();
```

How would one method effect the other?

Comment: Now it'll compile. No difference, but calling a static method in an instance is misleading and confusing.

Comment: okay, but if i had the object created and i called that method statically. how would it affect the int? Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static method in Java can be accessed using object instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978000/static-method-in-java-can-be-accessed-using-object-instance)

Comment: it was made feb. 2011 but if you mean i should have searched, i did and i guess it was my fault as i did not search with the correct keywords. Only after posting the example did i understand the concept. Either ways, thanks i get another point of reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is the same.

You should call it by class name, not through the instance, because *no dynamic dispatch* happens.

Most compilers will give you a warning, if you do that, too. [Some people argue that it should have been made a compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co?lq=1).

Comment: When you call a method on an object, the runtime will look at the actual runtime class of that object and call an overridden method if present. *This will not happen with static methods* (even though it might look like it if you call it through the instance). Static methods are always called in the class that you specified at compile-time. I.e. if your `secretNumber` was an instance of `SecretNumberSubClass`, the method in the parent class would still be called.

Comment: ahh, okay. So by calling methods statically you will not be calling similar overridden methods from extends? Also if i made an instance of that object and then called that method statically, how would the method effect the variables in the class?

Comment: It does not matter if you have an instance of the class when you call a static method. It is exactly the same as `ClassName.methodName()`. The instance is not used at all. It can even be null! `SecretNumber s = null; s.changeSecretNumber()` will work.

Comment: so if i called the static method and in the method it changed a private int. the int would not change at all correct? however if i called the same static method to change a static int the int would change?

Comment: You cannot access a "private" (if by that you mean instance variable) int in a static method. That won't even compile.

Comment: +1; the typing bit is important. I was going to mention the null thing but that seemed like too much ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Java, unless a class method is "static", you *can't* call it *except* through an object instance.

Here's an example of a method where it would make sense to declare it "static":

- http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/methods/50static-methods.html

  public static double mean(int[] p) {
     int sum = 0;  // sum of all the elements
     for (int i=0; i

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: my bad, the class is static. what would happen then?

Answer (score 0):

The second form isn't valid Java.  You can only call methods on a class if they are declared `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a method through a class is a static method. Unless you declare the method a static method, the compiler will give you a compile error .

Comment: What would the effect be on the number though? for example if i called the static method would all objects carrying that number be changed or what?

Comment: The int secretnumber is a **static** number . That means that there is class variable and this will be the same for all the objects . So if you increment the number , then yes , the number will change for all the objects.

Comment: So if i changed it to public secretNumber instead of static it wouldn't be affected?