# Calendar returns wrong month and year Java

Tags: java, date, calendar

```
    Calendar now = null;
    now.getInstance();
    System.out.println(now.getInstance());
    System.out.println(now.ERA);
    System.out.println(now.YEAR);
    System.out.println(now.MONTH);
    System.out.println(now.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    System.out.println(now.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println(now.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println(now.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    System.out.println(now.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    System.out.println(now.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);
```

Program outputs (important information is in caps and on the new line):

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1412554865330,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=9,WEEK_OF_YEAR=41,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_YEAR=278,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=5,HOUR_OF_DAY=17,MINUTE=21,SECOND=5,MILLISECOND=330,ZONE_OFFSET=-28800000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

(0-8 are on new lines)
I'm really loss here and am not sure why java decided play this awful prank on me.

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? What are you seeing that you don't expect? Perhaps the MONTH value? [*The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.)*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)

Comment: Oh, I see what your problem is. Try `System.out.println(now.get(Calendar.YEAR));`. Also, `Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are all `static` fields from the `Calendar` class. [Java allows `static` fields (and methods) to be accessed on expressions that resolve to an instance's reference value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978000/static-method-in-java-can-be-accessed-using-object-instance) the same way it does on type names

```
now.ERA
// is equivalent to
Calendar.ERA
```

The `Calendar` class provides a [`get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get-int-) method for getting the value of a date field.

```
now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Comment: I've  tried multiple ways of writing this including Calendar.getInstance().MONTH().  However the way you suggested causes a NullPointerException.  Calendar now = null; now.get(Calendar.MONTH); because now is null but must be initialized in order to use its methods.

Comment: @DavidFisher I've linked the javadoc. Don't just guess. Look at the available methods and use them. I've already supplied one example of getting the Month field from the `Calendar` instance.

Comment: @DavidFisher Initialize your reference before you invoke a method on it.

Comment: I'm a moron.  Initialize by Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

Just FYI, you might find working with the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library (or the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8) to be a more pleasant experience than using the java.util.Date & java.util.Calendar classes.

Both Joda-Time and java.time follow [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for defining week-of-year and for default string formats.

Here is the same kind of code but using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.4.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
java.util.Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withLocale( locale );
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now( timeZone );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "Full: " + formatter.print( dateTime ) );
System.out.println( "Era: " + dateTime.getEra() ); // 0 (BC/BCE) & 1 (AD/CE).
System.out.println( "Year: " + dateTime.getYear() );
System.out.println( "Month: " + dateTime.getMonthOfYear() );
System.out.println( "WeekOfYear: " + dateTime.getWeekOfWeekyear() ); // Standard ISO 8601 week.
//System.out.println( now.WEEK_OF_MONTH ); // Not in Joda-Time as there is no standard definition for week-of-month.
System.out.println( "DayOfMonth: " + dateTime.getDayOfMonth() );
System.out.println( "DayOfYear: " + dateTime.getDayOfYear() );
System.out.println( "DayOfWeek: " + dateTime.getDayOfWeek() ); // Starts at 1 rather than 0. Amazing!
//System.out.println( now.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH ); // Not in Joda-Time as there is no standard definition for week-of-month.
System.out.println( "TimeZone: " + dateTime.getZone() );
```

When run.

```
Full: dimanche 5 octobre 2014 21 h 22 EDT
Era: 1
Year: 2014
Month: 10
WeekOfYear: 40
DayOfMonth: 5
DayOfYear: 278
DayOfWeek: 7
TimeZone: America/Montreal
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend Java8's LocalDateTime and LocalTime classes if you can port into Java8

Otherwise I'd recommend using `GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar()`

```
cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) for example
```