# java static keyword

Tags: java, static, keyword

I know the definition of static which is a keyword to refer a variable or method to the class itself. Could this mean if I wrote a method called `parseInt()` in a class called `calculator` and another method called `parseInt()` in a different class called `mathProgram`, the compiler Eclipse will know which class the method `parseInt()` is referring to?

Answer (score 4):

You need to call static methods by referencing the class it is a part of:

```
MathProgram.parseInt();
```

Is not the same as

```
Calculator.parseInt();
```

So written this way it is clear to the JVM which method you were referring to.

**Edit:** You can also call static methods using an instance variable but this is in bad form and should be avoided.  See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co/610674#610674) answer for more info.

**Edit2:** Here's a link to the [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-137265.html#587) section regarding the use of calling static methods from instance variables.  (Thanks to [Ray Toal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/831878/ray-toal) for the link left in the answer to a [question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884004/is-calling-static-methods-via-an-object-bad-form-why))

Comment: True but that's in bad form, yes?

Comment: Hopefully, but for completeness, it must be brought up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because static methods and variables must be in a class and to call them outside of that class you need to qualify them.

For example `Calculator.parseInt()` and `OtherClass.parseInt()`.

Eclipse uses that to tell them apart.

Comment: *Java* uses that to tell them apart.

Comment: Eclipse uses Java to tell them apart.

Comment: And Java uses the class name to tell them apart. Eclipse has nothing to do with it. The program compiles and executes identically whether or not Eclipse is even there, *modulo* Eclipse peculiarities.

Comment: Right, but the question asked how does Eclipse know the difference so I thought I'd keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

If the method is static, you need to call it using the classname:

```
Calculator.parseInt();
```

Otherwise, with an instance:

```
Calculator c = new Calculator();
c.parseInt();
```

Either way, its explicit which you want.

Comment: Although it's generally considered bad practice to use an instance (i.e. `c.parseInt()`) to call a static method.

Comment: What the answer said is if its static, use the class name. If it is not static, use an instance.