# Is calling static methods via an object "bad form"? Why?

Tags: java, methods, static, instance

In a recent question, someone asked about static methods and one of the answers stated that you generally call them with something like:

```
MyClassName.myStaticMethod();
```

The comments on that also stated that you could also call it via an object with:

```
MyClassName myVar;
myVar.myStaticMethod();
```

but that it was considered bad form.

Now it seems to me that doing this can actually make my life easier so I don't have to *worry* about what's static or not <sup>(a)</sup>.

*Is* there some problem with calling static functions via an object? Obviously you wouldn't want to *create* a brand new object just to call it:

```
Integer xyzzy;
int plugh = xyzzy.parseInt ("42", 10);
```

But, if you already have an object of the desired type, is there a problem in *using* it?

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Obviously, I can't call a non-static method with:

```
MyClassName.myNonStaticMethod();
```

but that's not the issue I'm asking about here.

Comment: See this SO answer for info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co/610674#610674

Comment: When I read code and there is a call to a method, to me it's **highly** relevant to be able to tell right away that that call cannot read nor modify the state of the object it belongs to. With `MyClassName.myStaticMethod();` there isn't even the need to wonder about it for a second. With `myVar.myStaticMethod();` you need to see the method's code, and you will always be in this doubt for _all_ calls. Of course different IDEs might make this information easy to retrieve (Javadoc tooltips, syntax highlighting etc.) but I wouldn't rely on that to decide how to write the code.

Comment: SantiBailors: I'm not sure why you would need to know that. The whole point of encapsulation is that you *don't* know what it does to internal state, and you *shouldn't* - the class will do the right thing because it knows what to do.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The bad form comment comes from the Coding Conventions for Java

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-137265.html#587

The reason for it, if you think about it, is that the method, being static, does not **belong** to any particular object.  Because it belongs to the class, why would you want to elevate a particular object to such a special status that it appears to own a method?

In your particular example, you *can* use an existing integer through which to call `parseInt` (that is, it is legal in Java) but that puts the reader's focus on that particular integer object.  It can be confusing to readers, and therefore the guidance is to avoid this style.

Regarding this making life easier for you the programmer, turn it around and ask what makes life easier on the *reader*?  There are two kinds of methods: instance and static.  When you see a the expression `C.m` and you know `C` is a class, you know `m` must be a static method.  When you see `x.m` (where `x` is an instance) you can't tell,  but it looks like an instance method and so most everyone reserves this syntax for instance methods only.

Answer (score 42):

In my opinion, the real use case that makes this so unreadable is something like this.  What does the code below print?

```
//in a main method somewhere
Super instance = new Sub();
instance.method();

//...
public class Super {
    public static void method() {
        System.out.println("Super");
    }
}

public class Sub extends Super {
    public static void method() {
        System.out.println("Sub");
    }
}
```

The answer is that it prints "Super", because static methods are not virtual.  Even though `instance` is-a `Sub`, the compiler can only go on the type of the variable which is `Super`.  However, by calling the method via `instance` rather than `Super`, you are subtly implying that it will be virtual.

In fact, a developer reading the `instance.method()` would have to look at the declaration of the method (its signature) to know which method it actually being called.  You mention

> it seems to me that doing this can actually make my life easier so I don't have to worry about what's static or not

But in the case above context is actually very important!

I can fairly confidently say it was a mistake for the language designers to allow this in the first place.  Stay away.

Answer (score 6):

It's a matter of communication. Calling a method on an instance *implies* you're acting on/with that particular instance, not on/with the instance's class.

Answer (score 4):

It might get super confusing when you have an object that inherits from another object, overriding its static method.  Especially if you're referring to the object as a type of its ancestor class.  It wouldn't be obvious as to which method you're running.

Comment: If that "super confusing" was a pun, I'm going to have to come over and slap you around a bit :-)