# Any practical difference in the use of Java's static method main?

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point

If I have the following Java class :

```
public class MyClass
{
  ...

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
   ...
  }
}
```

Is there any practical difference if I call it in the 2 different ways below ?

```
[1] new Stock_Image_Scanner().main(null);
[2] Stock_Image_Scanner.main(null);
```

Comment: Depends on what the constructor does...

Comment: `MyClass.main(null)` is the proper way (static access)

Answer (score 6):

In the first one the constructor gets executed. In the second one it does not.

Comment: ANd in the first example an object is allocated (and gets available for garbage collection immediately if the constructor doesn'T save a reference to the object in any static property).

Answer (score 4):

`main` is a static function, and *should not* be called via an instance. It should only be called via the class name:

```
Stock_Image_Scanner.main(null);
```

In addition, `null` should really be changed to `new String[]{}`. And as stated @kg_sYy, the `new` way (via the instance) executes the classes constructor, which is generally unexpected and not recommended.

More info:

- [Why isn't calling a static method by way of an instance an error for the Java compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co)
- [Is calling static methods via an object "bad form"? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884004/is-calling-static-methods-via-an-object-bad-form-why)

Comment: +1 calling a static method via an instance is just confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Just to say the same thing in yet another way:

```
new Stock_Image_Scanner().main(null);
```

Does the same thing as:

```
new Stock_Image_Scanner();
Stock_Image_Scanner.main(null);
```