# Is assigning variables directly to a wrapper class a good practice in Java?

Tags: java, class, helper

As I am slowly progressing through the java tutorials, I came across java helper classes. The code is

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
char myLittleChar = 'b';
char myBigChar = Character.toUpperCase(myLittleChar);
System.out.println(myBigChar);
```

However, it worked the same even when assigning directly to a helper class.

```
Character c = 'a';
System.out.println(c.toUpperCase(c));
```

and the same applied for short or float as well.

However, I didn't come across this much in any tutorial, or any sample code, and is declared as `int`, `short` etc. Is it considered a bad practice? If so, why?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume you mean the wrapper classes for primitives when you speak about `Helper classes`. Using them is not per-se bad, but you should be aware that you create objects (even if yo do not call an explicit constructor) via [`autoboxing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). Since this is typically a big performance hit, one tries to avoid it.

Comment: c.toUpperCase(c) is a bad practice because it's a call to a static method and has to be done on Class not on an instance!

Comment: @Turing85 The video tutorial I followed was saying as `Helper class`, and not `wrapper class` and hence I was unaware and am not sure which is the correct terminology. The performance part makes sense. Thank you for the kind explanation.

Comment: @rlm Thank you for the kind explanation. I was looking for the reason to understand why is a bad practice. I guess, as Turing85 said, it is the performance hit.

Comment: We don't talk about the same thing : Turing talk about using 'char' instead of 'Character', I talk about using an instance to call a static method... See this thread to demonstrate what I said : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884004/is-calling-static-methods-via-an-object-bad-form-why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character wraps the primitive two-byte char in an object. That is superfluous.
You could write

```
char myBigChar = Character.toUpperCase('b');
```

So it is a matter of efficiency.

By the way String already is an object, and does not have this verbosity.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to know the utility ot wrapper `Object` classes versus their primitive counterparts.

There are many advantages to wrapper classes:

- They can be used as generic types
- They are nullable
- They provide utility methods on their wrapped primitive value and other static methods
- etc.

On the other side of your question, there's a concept called boxing / unboxing.

When you: `Character c = 'a';`, you are *autoboxing* primitive value `'a'` into its wrapper `Character` class.

If you follow that assignment with something like: `char a = c;`, you are automatically *unboxing* the wrapper's value into its primitive counterpart.