# Synchronization between two threads using same and different instance of class?

Tags: java

I would like to clear few doubts and extending question from here - [synchronization in two methods in the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32273979/synchronization-in-two-methods-in-the-same-class).

```
public class Demo {
    public synchronized void methodA(){
        System.out.println("Method A");
    }
    public synchronized void methodB(){
        System.out.println("Method B");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        Demo demo1 = new Demo();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> demo.methodA());
        thread1.start();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> demo1.methodB());
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

locks work at the instance level, not at the class level.

Case-1: For each instance of `Demo` at most one between method1 and method2 can be running at any given moment. This is clear.

Case-2: Two different instances are calling two separate method, will still the thread block each other?

Using **Static Synchronized** the same method -

```
public class Demo {
    public static synchronized void methodA(){
        System.out.println("Method A");
    }
    public static synchronized void methodB(){
        System.out.println("Method B");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        Demo demo1 = new Demo();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> demo.methodA());
        thread1.start();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> demo1.methodB());
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

Case-3: Say same instance of demo class `demo` is used to call two separate method, will they block each other?

Case-4: Say different instances of Demo class `demo` and `demo1` is used to call two separate method will they still block each other?

Comment: You've answered your own question. Locks work at the instance level unless the methods are `static`, which they aren't. *Ergo* two instances have two locks and they don't impede each other. Hard to understand why you're even asking.

Comment: Instances aren't used to invoke `static` methods. That syntax resolves the type of `demo`/`demo1` and finds a corresponding method on that type to invoke https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884004/is-calling-static-methods-via-an-object-bad-form-why

Comment: @nhatnq provides a very clear answer. Helpful topic about static synchronization: [Synchronization between two threads using same and different instance of class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120248/how-to-synchronize-a-static-variable-among-threads-running-different-instances-o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case2 No, the lock is for method's object. Each instance keeps a separate lock

Case3 Yes, the static method has association with a class not a object, so the lock is for the `Class` object. They block each other

Case4: Yes, since it's the class object, same result in invoking it on different instances

Answer (score 2):

The `synchronized` keyword on a method is in just about every relevant fashion simply syntax sugar. So let's desugar this, that makes it more clear:

```
class Test {
  synchronized void foo() {
    hello();
  }
}

// desugars to:

class Test {
  void foo() {
    synchronized (this) {
      hello();
    }
  }
}
```

And if we involve static:

```
class Test {
  static synchronized void staticFoo() {
    hello();
  }
}

// desugars to:

class Test {
  static void staticFoo() {
    synchronized (Test.class) {
      hello();
    }
  }
}
```

Now we just need to explain what `synchronized()` does, and perhaps what `Test.class` does.

Every object in java is also a locking object. It basically works like this:

- Every object has a hidden field that you cannot access, at all, but it does exist. It is of type `Thread` and is called `monitor`. It also has a second hidden, in accessible field `int monitorCount;`.
- Objects initially start out with a count of 0 and a `null` value for the `monitor` field.
- `synchronized(expr) {` means one of three things:
- If the object you find when you resolve `expr` currently has `monitor == null`, then execute: `monitor = Thread.currentThread(); monitorCount = 1;`, and enter the `{}` block.
- If the object you find when you resolve `expr` currently has `monitor == Thread.currentThread()`, then simply execute `monitorCount++` and enter the block.
- Otherwise (so, `monitor`'s value is some other thread), freeze this thread until `monitor` is `null`, then act as per the first rule.
- ... but of course the above 3 things occur atomically: The JVM guarantees that any 2 threads don't both draw the conclusion that `monitor` is `null` simultaneously or other such shenanigans. In other words, if you *actually* wrote this code, it wouldn't work, because you don't get that '... but atomically' guarantee, but `synchronized` does provide it.

`Test.class` is an exotic but entire valid java construct. Try it:

In java, any class has exactly one instance of the class `java.lang.Class` associated with it. Given any object you can get it using `obj.getClass()`. If you don't have an instance of a class, but you do know exactly what class you're talking about, the language construct `ThatClass.class` will get you that instance just the same. Let's try it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Class<?> stringClass = String.class;
  System.out.println(stringClass);
  System.out.println("".getClass() == String.class); // 'true'.
}
```

Note that without custom classloaders, these instances are singletons.

This then explains `static synchronized`: They're all locking on the exact class. Note that this class stuff doesn't inherit: If you have:

```
class Parent {
  static synchronized void parentMethod() {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  static synchronized void childMethod() {}
}
```

Then thread A can be executing parentMethod whilst at the same time thread B is executing childMethod as they are locking on different objects. (namely, `Child.class`, and `Parent.class`.

With that knowledge:

Case2: No, `instance1.monitor == threadA;` and `instance2.monitor == threadB;`, no problem. They won't block each other.

Case 3: Yes, as there is only one Demo.class.monitor`, and that can only be threadA or threadB. The one that it isn't, can't enter these methods and has to wait.

Case 4: Same as 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of examples to - hopefully - make it more obvious.

First the **Instance Demo:**

```
/**
 * Instance : the Threads run independently, synchronizing on the Instances
 */
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public final class Demo {

    private        final Random randomA = new Random();
    private        final Random randomB = new Random();

    private        void common(final String label, final Random random) {
        IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(n -> {

            final String       thread = Thread.currentThread().getName();

            System.out.println(thread + " Method " + label + "-1 n=" + n);

            try {Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(100));} catch (final InterruptedException e) {}

            System.out.println(thread + " Method " + label + "-2 n=" + n + "\n");

            try {Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(100));} catch (final InterruptedException e) {}
        });
    }

    private        synchronized void methodA() {common("A_", randomA);}
    private        synchronized void methodB() {common("_B", randomB);}

    public  static void main(final String[] args) {

        final Demo demoB = new Demo();

        new Thread(() -> new Demo().methodA(), "[Thread_Aa_]").start(); // Comment out
//      new Thread(() ->     demoB .methodA(), "[Thread__Ba]").start(); // Un-Comment
        new Thread(() ->     demoB .methodB(), "[Thread__Bb]").start();
    }
}
```

And now, the **Static Demo:**

```
/**
 * Static : the Threads block each other, synchronizing on the Class
 * 3 & 4) methodA & methodB are never interrupted
 * 3 & 4) calling static Methods from the Instance gives a Compiler Warning
 *        & actually executes DemoStatic.methodA(...) or DemoStatic.methodB(...)
 *        Warning:
 *        The static method x(.) from the type Y should be accessed in a static way
 */
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public final class DemoStatic {

    private static final Random randomA = new Random();
    private static final Random randomB = new Random();

    private static void common(final String label, final Random random, final int n) {

        final String       thread = Thread.currentThread().getName();

        System.out.println(thread + " Method " + label + "-1 n=" + n);

        try {Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(100));} catch (final InterruptedException e) {}

        System.out.println(thread + " Method " + label + "-2 n=" + n + "\n");

        try {Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(100));} catch (final InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    public static synchronized void methodA(final int n) {common("A_", randomA, n);}
    public static synchronized void methodB(final int n) {common("_B", randomB, n);}

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

//      @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        final Runnable loopA = () -> IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(n -> new DemoStatic().methodA(n));
        final Runnable loopB = () -> IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(n ->     DemoStatic  .methodB(n));

        new Thread(loopA, "[Thread_A_]").start();
        new Thread(loopB, "[Thread__B]").start();
    }
}
```