# Why does Java allow accessing of a static member with an object instance

Tags: java, oop

My understanding is that static members belong to the class. Why then does Java allow me to access them with an object?

To understand what I mean, please see the following example:

```
public class Student {
  public static int number = 0;
}
```

Here `number` is a static field that belongs to class `Student`, but I can still access it as shown below:

```
Student s = new Student();
int n = s.number;
```

What is the rationale behind this decision?

Comment: I tried to edit your question for clarity but couldn't. I can't understand what are you asking?

Comment: Google Translate at its best :)

Comment: @SoufianeHassou, perhaps my edit can help.

Comment: are you sure the code compiles in this case? I know for a fact c# throws a compilation error

Comment: Whol talked about C# here. Can you please specify from where are you calling `int n = s.number;`

Comment: @Baz1nga yes it works fine... but with a warning.

Comment: @m0skit0, please be sure to check the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11062293/revisions). The original wording of the question was a horrible mess.

Comment: you just can... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't calling a static method by way of an instance an error for the Java compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co)

Comment: Just because you can do it, doesn't mean you should. You should always access a field in a static way, like using `Student.number;` instead of `s.number;` which wasn't the question, but just pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rationale behind this is that an object is an instance of the class, and therefore it should be able to access every attribute that belongs to the class in addition to the the instance level attributes.

It's like traditional mail. If you receive a mail that were addressed to your whole family (static member), you will feel licenced to open it, because you are the member of the family. On the other hand, if the mail is addressed to you (instance member), only you have the right to open it, no one else in you family.

This also works the same in other object-oriented languages, like C++. However, it is discouraged to use the `s.number` notation to access static members, as it is misleading for the readers of your code. You should always use the `Student.number` notation, as this clearly shows that `number` is a static member. Modern languages, for example C# will issue a warning if you access static members via instance variable, but still it is perfectly legal according to the language specification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,you have sloved my puzzle dom .Beausce I use C#,so i have this.

Answer (score 4):

After some reading apparently  The java compiler does the necessary hoodoo to deal with object instances that access static variables and it knows what you want you meant.. IDEs will give you a warning about it ..

Regarding the why and explanation read this: [Why isn't calling a static method by way of an instance an error for the Java compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co)

ultimately it is a language spec and you just need to deal with it.. Its your call whether to use it or not.. My suggestion: **DONT!**

Answer (score 0):

The rationale behind this is... [JLS - Chapter 8.3.1.1. static Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1)

Comment: I don't see any rationale per-se in the JLS: just the plain fact that you can access it on an object.

Comment: +1 for reference. It's a choice they made when designing the language.

Comment: You are right, not a rationale per-se. The original question asked why he was able to do this. So I think the link might be helpful.