# Why doesn't Java allow hiding static methods by instance methods?

Tags: java, inheritance

As shown in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html, Java does allow

1. Overriding an instance method by an instance method and
2. Hiding a static method by a static method

My question is why Java doesn't allow *hiding a static superclass method by an instance method*. This could be done like this:

```
class Base {
    static void foo () {}
}

class Derived extends Base {
    void foo () {}
    void access () {
        foo ();
        Base.foo ();
    }
}
```

I don't see any particular issue with the above approach - it is only as "messy/complex" as the (allowed) hiding of statics already is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect it is to avoid confusion with dealing with the base class. In fact I imagine the designers didn't see an obvious way this should behave.

```
class Base {
    static void foo () {}
}

class Derived extends Base {
    void foo () {} // say this compiled
}

Base b = new Derived()
b.foo(); // should the static or the virtual method be called?
```

Should b.foo() call Base.foo() or should it potentially call Derived.foo()?

Comment: basically I think it boils down to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co

Answer (score 5):

**Simple answer**: that would be the mess.

**Concrete answer**: what to call in that case `Derived.foo()`? `Base.foo()` can't be called as it's hidden (as per you), `Derived.foo()` can't be called as it's not static.

Comment: Good example. I think this should result in a compile time error for the reasons you gave. Instead, the code should either `Base.foo()` or `new Derived().foo()` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Because, one are like Bananas and the other ones are Apples.

Explaination:

- Static Methods are created when reading the Class-Structure
- Methods are created when a object of a class is created.

Example:

```
Foo.bar();
```

is something different than

```
new Foo().bar();
```

Guess which one is called?

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f.bar();
```

Comment: From my point of view (which is biased by C#) it is clear: The method was called on an object, so the instance method is called instead of the static method. In Java though, I think it is allowed to call static methods on an object (design mistake imo), which leads to the confusion you're explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Another to add here is:
1. Static methods belong at the class level. So u cannot override method in the derived class.
   as simple its called hiding. :)
2. Instance methods belong to the objects, so objects are overrided. So we can override in the derived class.

Above other comments give a good example have a look into it..

Regards
Punith

Comment: The question is why we can't hide static methods by instance methods (opposed to hiding with static methods, which works fine as you explained).