# Can't access static field via `super` from within subclass?

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-error, super

```
package morepackage;

public class Subclass extends Superclass {
  public static void main ( String args[] )
  {
    String name = super.text;//error in this line
    String name1 = Superclass.text;//no error in this line
  }}
```

The code of the superclass is:

```
public class Superclass {
  static String text = "flowers";
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why the line `String name = super.text` is ***showing error***

While the line `String name1 = Superclass.text;` is ***not showing error*** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`super` refers to the parent **class** of the actual **object**. In the main method there is nothing like "actual object" because it is a static scope.

The Superclass's attribute `text` is defined as **static** so you can access it throught it class name inside the **static** main method.

Don't you confound **class** with **object** (or **instance**).

Answer (score 1):

The method `main` is `static`, there is no such thing as `super` inside a `static` method.

Comment: but the main method is contained in a subclass of a superclass ??

Answer (score 1):

`main` is a static method and thus not able to access references to `this` and `super`.

In any event, even if this you did obtain an instance to a `Subclass` (e.g. via `new`), it is not good practice to access [static members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co) of classes via class instance, hence the access `Superclass.text` is the correct way to refer to "Flowers".