# An enum constant contains all the enum constants of the same enum class

Tags: java, enums

I just realized that an enum constant in Java seems containing all the enumeration constants of the same type.

For example, the following code is legitimate:

```
enum State {
    enable, disable, deleted;
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for ( State s : State.enable.disable.values() ) {
            System.out.println(s);
         }
    }
}
```

I was very surprised when I saw that the output is:

```
enable
disable
deleted
```

Isn't it counter-intuitive or even illogical that the `enable` constant contains `disable` constant which in turn constains all the `State` enum constants?

What is the possible consideration behind this language design?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co

Comment: **Just switch your warnings on:** "The static field State.disable should be accessed in a static way."

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Designers made a mistake when they first designed Java: static members, which belong to the class itself, and not to any instance of the class, can be accessible using an instance of the class. consider this class:

```
class Foo {
    public static int bar = 0;
}
```

You *should* normally access the bar variable using

```
int i = Foo.bar;
```

But you *can* also do

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
int i = foo.bar;
```

That's what's happening here. `enable`, `disable`, `values()`, are static members of the class `State` that should be accessed using `State.enable`, `State.disable` and `State.values()`. But `enable` and `disable` are also *instances* of the class `State`, and can thus also be used to access static members of the class:

```
State state = State.enable;
State state2 = state.disable;
```

or simpler:

```
State state2 = State.enable.disable;
```

Uglier, you could even do that without getting a NullPointerException:

```
State state = null;
State[] allStates = state.values();
```

Comment: This isn't a mistake, compiler replace instance variable with the class name during compilation time.

Comment: @Yurets JB is not suggesting that the compiler made a mistake, but that the designers of Java made a mistake.

Answer (score 13):

`values()` is a *static method*. The Java language allows you to call a class's static method on any instance of that class, but the instance is ignored.

Same for `enable`, `disable` and `deleted`, which are static fields.

`State.enable` doesn't contain `disable`; rather, `State.enable.disable` is treated the same as `State.disable`. And `State.enable.disable.values()` is treated the same as `State.disable.values()`, which is treated the same as `State.values()`, which of course returns an array of all three values.

Answer (score 4):

`.values()` is an implicit **`static`**  method on the `enum` and no matter on which value are you invoking it, you'll get the same result as `State.values()`.

It's pretty much the same are you were invoking a static method on an instance (instead by directly referring the class name).

Actually, invoking `static` methods on instances, should raise a warning, which *hints* that you're doing improperly.