# Calling static methods using an instance of that class

Tags: java, syntax, static

I understand that to call static methods , we do not need an instance of a class. We can directly call it using the class name. For the code below:

```
Class Demo
{
  Integer instVariable;

  // Static method
  public static Integer someUtility(Integer arg)
  {
     // Perform some calculations and return the result back
  }

  // Non static method
  public void changeState()
  {
     // Change instance behaviour
  }
}
```

I can call the static method

```
Demo.someUtility(42);
```

Yet Java also allows the following syntax

```
Demo someRef = new Demo();
someRef.someUtility(42);
```

I am trying to understand why Java would support a syntax like this. Because `someUtility` is being called using a dot operator on a reference , it implies that this method has knowledge about the object that `someRef` is referencing (which it does not). It's just misleading.

I am just wondering if there were other considerations.

Comment: You'd still have a warning but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co

Comment: @AlexisC. thanks for pointing it out. Sufficiently answers my question.