# Why cannot use this while calling static interface method from default interface method?

Tags: java, interface

Why **when in interface**, *calling static interface method from default interface method I cannot use `this.staticInterfaceMethod()`*, **while when in regular class**, *calling static class method from instance method it is perfectly valid to use* `this.staticClassMethod()` (though it is bad style)?

At the same time, it is perfectly valid to use `this` within default methods of interface - I can legally do the following:

```
interface I {   
    int MY_CONST = 7;   
    static void st_f() {}       
    default void f1() {}

    default void f_demo() {
        this.f1();                  // fine!
        int locvar = this.MY_CONST; // also fine! 

        this.st_f(); // c.ERR:  static method of interface I can only be accessed as I.st_f 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709082/illegal-static-interface-method-call/34709162. See Brian Goetz's comment "We consider the ability to invoke a static method through an instance to be a language design error, unfortunately one which we can't fix retroactively for classes. We could at least not make the same mistake [with interfaces]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Static method may be invoked on containing interface class only."

Static methods are not inherited from an interface by the class that implements the interface ([§8.4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8)). The `this` keyword refers to the current object, hence attempting to invoke `this.staticInterfaceMethod()` would imply that somehow an Object exists that has inherited the static interface method. This cannot happen; interfaces cannot be instantiated by themselves and any implementation of the interface did not inherit the static method. Thus, `this.staticInterfaceMethod()` does not exist so you would need to invoke the method on the Interface itself.

A simplified explanation as to why you don't inherit the static method is the following scenario:

```
public interface InterfaceA {
    public static void staticInterfaceMethod() {
        ...
    }
}

public interface InterfaceB {
    public static void staticInterfaceMethod() {
        ...
    }
}

public class ClassAB implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
    ...
}
```

What static method would `ClassAB` inherit? The two static methods have the same signature and thus would be unidentifiable on a call; neither would hide the other.

> At the same time, it is perfectly valid to use this within default methods of interface.

Using the `this` keyword to reference default methods, variables and etc is permitted as *every* Object that can exist that inherits from the interface will inherit these properties.