# Periods class implementation in java 8

Tags: java, class, java-time, method-chaining, period

If I code like this:

```
Period wrong = Period.ofYears(1).ofWeeks(1);
```

It gives output of **`P7D`**.

By the implementation of `Period` class we know that all `of____()` methods are static.

But if you to do same chaining with `DateTime` class:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 20);
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(5, 15);
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(date, time)
  .minusDays(1).minusHours(10).minusSeconds(30);
```

All `minus___()` and `plus___()` methods are instance methods in `LocalDateTime` class.

Question: why is **method chaining** not allowed for the `Period` class?

Why the `Period` class isn't supporting that?

How  the internal assignment is going on ?

Comment: You can not chain the of() methods

Comment: You can chain calls of method from the Persion class if you would use the proper methods ...

Comment: Maybe I am too naive today, but I dont think you deserve all these downvotes coming in ... yes, it seems naive to chain static calls, but you clearly ask "why" the Period class isn't supporting that.

Comment: @GhostCat And can you answer that "why"? The only group of people telling OP why these methods are all static are the designers/developers of that class. We can just guess.

Comment: @Tom I think I gave that answer. It is because ofA().ofB() doesn't carry a reasonable semantic. Compare that to ofA().plus(ofB()) - like the other answer is showing!

Comment: @GhostCat You've explained how these methods work and why OPs code doesn't work, but you haven't explained _why_ the designers added these methods and not such builder methods like `LocalDateTime` has. That can only be answered by the designers themselves :/. We're interpreting OPs "why" differently.

Comment: The creation part in Period as well as LocalDateTime/LocalDate etc. is handled in the similar way by means of static factory methods. You can write `LocalDate today = LocalDate.of(2017, 06, 02).of(2018, 8, 31);` and this will ultimately give you the date 2018-08-31. But what you are trying to do here won't make sense. The purpose of chaining is to enable the manipulations to the date/time in a fluent easily readable and understandable way. So, even in Period class,you can write `Period.ofYears(1).plusYears(2)` which results in a Period of 3 years.

Comment: Of course it's allowed: `Period.ofYears(10).plusMonths(1).plusDays(1).minusYears(3)...` Only the chaining of the `of__()` methods are not *"allowed"* for all the reasons already explained (semantics, the way they were designed to work, etc). But I agree with @Tom that only the API designers can tell us **why**. For us, the only answer we can provide to *"Why?"* is *"Because it was designed to work like that"*. Basically, `of` creates a new object, `plus` and `minus` methods can be chained. Why? Because the API creators decided to do it this way.

Comment: You can't chain static methods, period. And you _have_ to have static methods to start, basically, or a constructor. There's no way for any class to be able to chain the initial factory methods, only instance methods like `plusYears` etc, which is exactly what Period does. There's no way it _could_ have been designed the way you're describing other than what they actually did.

Comment: You can do that instead: LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse("2020-01-01").minusMonths(1).minusDays(1).plusYears(10);
        System.out.println(d);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are **not** chaining calls in your first example.

```
Period wrong = Period.ofYears(1).ofWeeks(1);
```

is the same as:

```
Period wrong = Period.ofWeeks(1);
```

In other words: the object returned by `ofYears()` does not affect the result of `ofWeeks()` and it's year value will be discarded. You are invoking the **static** method `ofWeeks()`. What you are doing there is **not** a fluent call chain.

And any decent IDE should warn you about doing so. The reason is simple: this "chaining" simply doesn't make sense!

The `ofXyz()` calls create a new Period object for you. That object is *done* and created. What should be the semenatics of **chaining** another `ofXyz()` call onto the existing period?

In other words: you can't chain `ofXyz()` calls because there is no clear way to express the *semantics* that such a chain should have!

Comment: I know this. My question is Why is it so ?

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra Why is it so: Because that is just how these methods are designed to work.

Comment: The `of` methods are static factory methods. Factory methods create a new object, they are static so have no previous state. The `with`, `plus` and `min` methods can be chained, since Period is immutable, a new object is returned while the new state is passed to the new object. So there is a difference between factories (the creation of objects) and an object being immutable. A static factory method (of) cannot have the same name as a non static method, so one is called `of` and the others starts with `with`, `plus` or `min`...

Answer (score 9):

Period allows to chain methods have a look to instance methods `plus`, `plusDays` etc.

```
Period.ofYears(1).plus(Period.ofWeeks(1));
```

Comment: Nice enhancement. I overlooked those other methods there ;-)

Comment: Tbh I would use `Period.ofWeeks(1).plusYears(1);`.

Comment: Or Period.ofYears(1).plusDays(7); or new Period(1,0,7); looking at documentation Period is an amount of years months and days. Periods can be for example 2Y and 400D or 2Y and 16M.

Answer (score 6):

> By the implementation of Period class we know that all of____ ()
>   methods are static.

Exactly.

So `Period.ofYears(1)` will give you an instance of `Period` *but* you are not using this instance for anything useful.

Instead, you are invoking the static method `ofWeeks` on this instance. Doing this will give you a compiler warning, precisely for the reason you've demonstrated - it looks misleading.

This question talks a bit about this behaviour: [Why isn't calling a static method by way of an instance an error for the Java compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610458/why-isnt-calling-a-static-method-by-way-of-an-instance-an-error-for-the-java-co) In my opinion it's a poor design choice of Java to be able to do this at all.

> If you to do same chaining with DateTime Class ... all minus___() and
>   plus___() methods are instance methods in LocalDateTime Class

These methods still exist in `Period`, except for `plusWeeks`. Instead, you can do this:

```
// 1 year and 5 weeks
Period.ofYears(1).plusDays(5 * 7);
```

Comment: Or use `Period.ofWeeks(1).plusYears(1);`.

Comment: @Tom I think there's value in keeping things in descending size order. It's feels slightly unnatural to read it as "a week and a year". But still, a good alternative.